possible to map types to next size integer in rust?
I'd like to write something equivalent to this (example code is invalid but hopefully gets the point across). Is it possible in Rust, or why not? I'm open to any amounts of nightly/unstable.
trait MinimalBiggerUint {
  type Uint: Sized + Copy;
}

impl<T: Sized> MinimalBiggerUint for T {
  // Not meant to be overridden but I don't care so much about enforcing that.
  type Uint = const { 
    if core::mem::size_of::<T>() <= core::mem::size_of::<u32>() {
      u32
    } else if core::mem::size_of::<T>() <= core::mem::size_of::<u64>() {
      u64
    } else {
      panic!() // I want a compile error if used on a type larger than u64
    }
  }
}



This is sounding some alarm bells in my head.  Are you wanting to do this in order to transmute arbitrary types to/from some raw binary representation?  If so, there are almost certainly much better ways.

This would require the incomplete generic_const_exprs feature in order to use size_of::<T>() in a generic context required to map to a type. If that works for you then here is a potential solution:
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait MinimalBiggerUint {
  type Uint: Sized + Copy;
}

impl<T: Sized> MinimalBiggerUint for T where Size<{core::mem::size_of::<T>()}>: IntSize {
  type Uint = <Size<{core::mem::size_of::<T>()}> as IntSize>::Uint;
}

struct Size<const N: usize>;

trait IntSize {
    type Uint: Copy;
}

impl IntSize for Size<0> { type Uint = u32; }

impl IntSize for Size<1> { type Uint = u32; }
impl IntSize for Size<2> { type Uint = u32; }
impl IntSize for Size<3> { type Uint = u32; }
impl IntSize for Size<4> { type Uint = u32; }

impl IntSize for Size<5> { type Uint = u64; }
impl IntSize for Size<6> { type Uint = u64; }
impl IntSize for Size<7> { type Uint = u64; }
impl IntSize for Size<8> { type Uint = u64; }

There may be a better way to avoid the helper trait and its repetition, but this is probably concise enough. You will get a compiler error if you try to use a MinimalBiggerUint constraint with a type larger than 8 bytes.

one nuisance is that this requires some extra boilerplate with generic types. E.g. even though *mut T is 8 bytes for all T, I have to add a where *mut T: MinimalBiggerUint bound

Well *mut T is not 8 bytes for all T, unsized Ts make pointers fat (16 bytes). But beyond that, yes you will need a : MinimalBiggerUint constraint if you want to use it on a generic type since generic types, in general, can change size with different Ts.
